# Animating an activity when starting another activity

Tags: android, android-annotations

I have an activity in my application. Activity is Visible.When i want to go to home screen i want to Animate (fade_out) activity on Activity. I have tried the following code but that is not working.

**From Activity**

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        gotoHome();
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.animator.fade_out,android.R.animator.fade_in);
    }

    private void gotoHome() {
        Intent startHomescreen = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startHomescreen.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startHomescreen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(startHomescreen);
    }
```

When Launching activity A from my launcher Activity i add the following flag to the intent

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION
```

I also have tried it without using the above flag.

Can anybody tell me where am i wrong or suggest me anything helpful ?

Comment: Are you sure this is related to AndroidAnnotations?

Answer (score 0):

activity A :

```
startActivity(new Intent(A.this, B.class));
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.animator.enter_slidein,R.animator.exit_slideout);
```

activity B :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(B.this, A.class));
    finish(); 
    overridePendingTransition(R.animator.enter_slidein,R.animator.exit_slideout);
}
```

Comment: Yes i tried overridePendingTransition(R.animator.enter_slidein,R.animator.exit_slideout); below gotoHome(). its not animating while going to home screen

Comment: remove gotoHome method just add this code. i copied this code from my project and work perfectly.

Comment: I Just commented gotoHome() and now i have finish() method call and right after it i have overridePendingTransition() call but still now animating . . .

Comment: I am adding these flags when i am calling activity "A" 
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);